# A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have created a model which takes an input layer and produces two output layers.

```
 model = Model(inputs=efficient_net.input, outputs=[reg_pred, class_pred])
```

I am training the model , receiving the results and saving 2 instances of model in two .h5 files.

Then, I am putting the 2 models in a list:

```
model_weights = []
for item in os.listdir(packages_root):
    if ".h5" in item:
        model_weights.append(item)
```

So, I have `['model_2.h5', 'model_1.h5']`

Now, I am trying to ensemble:

```
def ensemble(models, model_input):
    
    Models_output = [model(model_input) for model in models]
    Avg = Average()(Models_output)
    
    ensemble = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=Avg, name='ensemble')
    ensemble.summary()
    ensemble.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
    
    return ensemble
```

Then I do:

```
model_input = Input(shape=models[0].input_shape[1:])
```

which gives : `<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'input_12')>`

and:

```
ensemble_model = ensemble(models, model_input)
```

which gives me:

`ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.`

on the line: `Avg = Average()(Models_output)`.

So , I am trying to do:

```
def ensemble(models, model_input):
    
    Models_output = []
    for model in models:
        Models_output.append(model(model_input))
        
    # Concatenate the 2 output layers
    Conc = Concatenate()([Models_output[0], Models_output[1])
    Avg = Average()(Conc)
    
    ensemble = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=Avg, name='ensemble')
    ensemble.summary()
    ensemble.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
    
    return ensemble
```

which now gives me:

`ValueError: A` Concatenate `layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs`

Note that, `print(Models_output)`, gives:

```
[[<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model_1')>, <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model_1')>],

 [<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model_2')>, <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model_2')>]]
```

Comment: From the last print it looks like your outputs are a _list of lists_ (of tensors), whereas they need to be a list of tensors.

Comment: @xdurch0:I am just trying to keep the 2 outputs in order to average on them. But I am using `[Models_output[0], Models_output[1]`

Comment: @George your base models produce 2 outputs... you are averaging 2 models which produce 2 outputs... The error is simple but for me, it's difficult to understand the result u want to achieve

Comment: @MarcoCerliani:Sorry, my last comment was wrong. I want to ensemble on the 2 models I have saved. So, I still want to take the Average on them.My ensemble will produce either one concatenated output with the predictions, either two outputs.

Comment: @George thanks, I added below my proposal... In the ensemble, I try to merge the two trained models... The ensemble will produce 2 outputs as the two base models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you call the `Average` layer on a list of lists and not on a list of tensors. This is because your models produce 2 outputs (`reg_pred`, `class_pred`).

You can fix the problem by simply building 2 `Average` layers: one for reg output and another one for class output

Here a dummy example where we fit 2 models to produce 2 outputs:

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (64,28,28,1))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, 64)

def get_model():
    inp = Input((28,28,1))
    reg_pred = Dense(1)(inp)
    class_pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(Flatten()(inp))
    model = Model(inp, [reg_pred, class_pred])
    model.compile('adam', ['mse', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'])
    return model

model1 = get_model()
model1.fit(X,[X,y])
model2 = get_model()
model2.fit(X,[X,y])
```

**Your ensemble funcion produces the error:**

```
def ensemble(models, model_input):
    
    Models_output = [model(model_input) for model in models]
    Avg = Average()(Models_output)
    
    ensemble = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=Avg, name='ensemble')
    ensemble.compile('adam', ['mse', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'])
    
    return ensemble

model_input = Input((28,28,1))
models = [model1, model2]
model_ensemble = ensemble(models, model_input)
```

**How to fix it:**

```
def ensemble(models, model_input):
    
    output_reg = []
    output_class = []
    for model in models:
        out_reg, out_class = model(model_input)
        output_reg.append(out_reg)
        output_class.append(out_class)
    avg_reg = Average()(output_reg)
    avg_class = Average()(output_class)
    
    ensemble = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=[avg_reg, avg_class], name='ensemble')
    ensemble.compile('adam', ['mse', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'])
    
    return ensemble

model_input = Input((28,28,1))
models = [model1, model2]
model_ensemble = ensemble(models, model_input)
```